# Mock request module function using jest in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am trying mock `request()` function of node module `request` using `jest` in typescript but I was unable to do that, can someone help me where was going wrong? By the way, I am trying to create a generic proxy function that should work with all http methods such as get, post, delete, update. So I want to use `request()` function only instead of request.get(),request.post()...etc using an if-else ladder based on the request method.

Proxy.ts:

```
import * as request from 'request';

export default class ProxyClass {
  static proxy(req: any, res: any): any {
    const options: any = {
      headers: req.headers,
    }
    const proxyReq: any = request(options);
    proxyReq.on('error', (err: any) => {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    });
    return proxyReq.pipe(res);
  }
}
```

Proxy.spec.ts:

```
import 'jest';
import * as request from 'request';
import {Request} from 'jest-express/lib/request';
import {Response} from 'jest-express/lib/response';
import ProxyClass from './Proxy';

describe('proxy request', () => {
  const req: any = new Request();
  const res: any = new Response();
  it('should call pipe', () => {
    const mockRequest = {
      pipe: jest.fn(),
      on: jest.fn(),
    }

    jest.mock('request', () => {
      return function() {
        return mockRequest;
      }
    });

    ProxyClass.proxy(req, res);
    expect(mockRequest.pipe).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
});
```

And when I run above test, I am getting the error:
`TypeError: request is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting `TypeError: request is not a function` then you probably have `esModuleInterop` set to `true` in your TypeScript config.

If that is the case then you'll need to import `request` like this:

```
import request from 'request';
```

TypeScript and ES6 modules are different than the older module style and the `esModuleInterop` flag tells TypeScript to do some extra work to compile `import` statements of older modules to work as if they were the newer style...in this case treating the single function export as if it were the `default` export of a TypeScript/ES6 module.

---

`jest.mock` [doesn't work inside a test](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2582) so you'll need to move it outside the test.

If you are passing a factory function as the second parameter then it needs to be completely self-contained since the call to `jest.mock` gets hoisted and will run before anything else in the test file.

In this case you can make your mock return the same object every time so you can get the mock during your test and check that it was called as expected:

```
import request from 'request';
import {Request} from 'jest-express/lib/request';
import {Response} from 'jest-express/lib/response';
import ProxyClass from './Proxy';

jest.mock('request', () => {
  const mockRequest = {
    pipe: jest.fn(),
    on: jest.fn(),
  }
  return function() {
    return mockRequest;  // <= returns the same object every time...
  }
});

describe('proxy request', () => {
  const req: any = new Request();
  const res: any = new Response();
  it('should call pipe', () => {
    const mockRequest = request();  // <= ...so you can get it here
    ProxyClass.proxy(req, res);
    expect(mockRequest.pipe).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  // Success!
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
});
```

(note that you don't need to import `jest` since `jest` loads and runs your test files and has already inserted itself into the global scope)